# I'm trying to download Blue Kik, but it keeps giving me the 'App not installed' message

Tags: installation, apk

I'm using a TCL LX (which I wouldn't doubt is the problem, due to how bad the phone is) and I'm looking for a simple solution. I've tried installing it multiple times, deleting and re-downloading the APK, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: maybe android 8.1 is not supported. ask the [support](https://bluesmods.com/#info) or post in [forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3961249)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get this message if there is not enough storage space on the device, so I would check that and try to free up space by deleting old files or unused apps.